# Multi-dimensional array of blittable type - how to get pinned unsafe poiner to memory?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

let's say you have a

```
Array array;
```

Assume that:

1. The type of this array is [blittable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blittable_types)
2. The array may have an *arbitrary number* of dimensions `(1..N)` *not known* at compile-time

Based on the assumptions, I believe we can assume the .Net framework will have stored its contents in a *contiguous region in memory*. How can I get a *fixed pointer* to that memory?

Something like a.. working version.. of

```
// Doesn't work, 
// gives "cannot take the address of the given expression"
fixed(object* ptr = &array.GetValue(0))
{
  // ...
}
```

or

```
// Doesn't work, dimensions unknown at compile-time, 
// so could be T[,], or T[,,], or T[,,,] etc. as well
T[] arr = (T[])array;
fixed(object* ptr = &T[0])
{
  // ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: this is a very interesting one; I'm taking a peek... but question: is the N *truly* arbitrary, or could we reasonably assume that it is not known at compile-time, but in a predictable range like 1-8 ? Also: can we reasonably assume that it will be 0-based? (non-zero-based arrays make me cry)

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell . For context: This is part of an IPC mechanism. I'm serializing data from one application, in this case a SAFEARRAY, into a custom binary format, and want to deserialize that in a C# application into a regular array. By definition of my protocol it will be zero based (I refuse to support non-zero based indices!! ;). Dimensions are truly arbitrary tho - while very unlike someone would create some 100-dimensional safearray in the other app, I can't rule it out for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for `Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` (you can ask for element 0 if you just want the root); the caveat here, however, is that you'll need to do the pinning manually (presumably with `try`/`finally`) - you can't use `fixed` with `Array`. This has more overhead than a simple `fixed` reference (which is just an IL flag on a "local" declaration)

---

Note: if you're always after the position of element 0, then `AddrOfPinnedObject()` on the `GCHandle` will also give you that, without needing the `Marshal` step.

Comment: Great, this looks very promising! I'll look into that - maybe in combiantion with GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned)

Comment: @Bogey for reference, I've done a quick check and this actually turns out to be the same as `handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()`, if you're just after the root...